# Spring Roo Generating Unknown Domain Model

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-roo

I have just started to use Spring Roo and I am encountering issues when generating a simple project with an entity. I am following a write up from DZone.

[DZone How to generate spring boot application](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-generate-spring-boot-applications-using-spr)

When I follow the steps I generate a domain model called owner with 2 fields

1. Username
2. Email

When I finish generating the project it corrected created the Owner model but there are references to QOwner in the code which are unable to find their class.

```
@RooJpaRepositoryCustomImpl(repository = OwnerRepositoryCustom.class)
public class OwnerRepositoryImpl extends QueryDslRepositorySupport{

    OwnerRepositoryImpl() {
        super(Owner.class);
    }

    private JPQLQuery getQueryFrom(QOwner qEntity){
        return from(qEntity);
    }
}
```

[image: OwnerRepositoryImple_Roo_Jpa_Repository_Impl.java]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that the `Q` classes are generated by the `querydsl-maven-plugin`, so you must compile the project using `mvn clean compile` to have these classes available.

After that, if you are using Eclipse STS or IntelliJ, you need to mark the folder where this `Q` classes are generated (*target/generated-sources/java*) as `Source Folder` to allow your IDE to detect them.

Hope it helps,